# Poisson process - expected reward until time t

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

The calls to the fire department occur according to a Poisson process with a rate of three per day. The fire department must respond to each call. Of the calls that come into the fire department, on the average one third turn out to be false alarms.
Firemen are presently paid 140 Dollars a day. A new plan is proposed where they will be paid a random amount of money per fire that they actually fight. In the new scheme the expected pay per fire fought is 60 Dollars. Determine the expected reward until time t.

[Resnick, Adventures in Stochastic Processes]

My approach is the following: Let $T _n=\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{N_ t}X_ i $ where $T _n$ is the time of the nth call and $X _i $ the time between the calls. The number of calls in $[0,t]$ is given as $N _t = \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^{\infty}1 _{(T_ n\leq t)}$. Let $Y _n$ the reward associated with $X_ n$. Then we have for the total reward at time t:
$R _t = \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{N _t}Y_ i $.

So what I have to do now is to compute the expected value of $R_t$ . How can I do that? Can I use Wald's identity:
$E(R _t)=E(N _t)E(Y _i)$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $N_t$ is independent of each $Y_i$, you can use it. Similarly, you could utilize law of iterated expectations:
$$E[R_t]=E\left[E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N_t} Y_i\big|N_t\right]\right]=E[N_t\underbrace{E[Y_i|N_t]}_{E[Y_i]}]=E[N_t]E[Y_i]$$

You also need to account for false positives inside $Y_i$.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm still stuck at how to calculate $E(N _t)$ and $E(Y _i)$ Is the expected value of $Y _i$ just 60 dollars? And $E( N _t)=2t$ (because there are two positive alarms per day..? it seems too easy for me but I don't know what I'm getting wrong here.

Comment: It's either $60\times 2/3=40$ dollars per event and $N_t=3t$, or $N_t=2t$ and $60$ dollars. The multiplication will be the same. It depends how you define $N_t$ and $Y_i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So the overall answer to my question would just be $E(R _t)=120t$ . I'm just a little bit confused because it feels like a very easy answer to me.

Comment: @sunflower234 yes, it is.